# Django add data to database from HTML page

Tags: django

Every applicant should enter their data from HTML page and this datas must insert to database. I think I did everything right, but datas are not shown in database. Here are my codes.

models.py:

```
class Applicant(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=40)
    motivation_letter = models.TextField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

views.py:

```
def apply(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        if request.POST.get('motivation_letter'):
            applicant = Applicant()
            applicant.name = request.POST.get('name')
            applicant.surname = request.POST.get('surname')
            applicant.phone = request.POST.get('phone')
            applicant.email = request.POST.get('email')
            applicant.motivation_letter = request.POST.get('motivation_letter')
            applicant.save()
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

HTML:

```
<form method="POST">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <label>Ad</label><br />
                    <input type="text" name="name"><br />
                    <label>Soyad</label><br />
                    <input type="text" name="surname"><br />
                    <label>Telefon nömrəsi</label><br />
                    <input type="number" name="phone"><br />
                    <label>Elektron poçt</label><br />
                    <input type="email" name="email"><br />
                    <label>Something else</label><br />
                    <textarea class="smth-else-textarea" cols="30" rows="10" name="motivation_letter"></textarea><br />
                    <input type="submit" value="Göndər" class="apply-button"/>
                </form>
```

Comment: Try adding the URL for your view in form action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use **model_name**.objects.create(xx=something..) to insert data.

```
def apply(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    if request.POST.get('motivation_letter'):

        Applicant.objects.create(
        name = request.POST.get('name'),
        surname = request.POST.get('surname'),
        phone = request.POST.get('phone'),
        email = request.POST.get('email'),
        motivation_letter = request.POST.get('motivation_letter'))

return render(request, 'index.html')
```

html : (if you don't work , try it : app_name:apply)

```
<form action="{% url "apply" %}" method='POST' > {% csrf_token %}
      <label>Ad</label><br />
      <input type="text" name="name"><br />
      <label>Soyad</label><br />
      <input type="text" name="surname"><br />
      <label>Telefon nömrəsi</label><br />
      <input type="number" name="phone"><br />
      <label>Elektron poçt</label><br />
      <input type="email" name="email"><br />
      <label>Something else</label><br />
      <textarea class="smth-else-textarea" cols="30" rows="10" 
      name="motivation_letter"></textarea><br />
       <input type="submit" value="Göndər" class="apply-button"/>
       </form>
```

urls.py: (not : import your views)

```
path('apply/', views.apply , name='apply'),
```

Comment: @srvqaqa sorry, I forgot to put a comma. I edited code, can you try one more.

Comment: I'm so sorry, but again I can't add data to db

Comment: here is my ```admin.py```  :


```class ApplicantAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'surname', 'phone', 'email', 'motivation_letter', 'is_accepted', 'photo')
admin.site.register(Applicant, ApplicantAdmin)
```

Comment: did you add urls your func? and your form url doesn't match. I edited my answer.